# What programs does Mac come with?

Tags: macos, installation

I am looking for a list of programs that come factory installed on OSX.

Some examples I know of would be Ruby, Tar and Gzip.

Is this listed anywhere? Perhaps from Apple in release notes or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might take at http://opensource.apple.com/, specifically at http://opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-107/.

Note that some of the common commands are hidden under group project names, like the following:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-212/

http://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-162/

http://opensource.apple.com/source/basic_cmds/basic_cmds-51/

For the definitive list, if you are on a Mac with OS X installed, you can use `/usr/bin/lsbom` (ls Bill-Of-Materials) to examine the BOMs from your installation:

```
/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.BSD.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.Essentials.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemBinaries.bom
```

(Do you have a Mac to run the `lsbom` on, or do you need the output from it?)

Answer (score 2):

It's a little long, but here's the results of `ls -m /usr/bin`:

```
`2to3, 2to32.6, BuildStrings, CpMac, DeRez, GetFileInfo, ImageUnitAnalyzer, 
MergePef, MvMac, PPCExplain, R, R32, R64, RSA_SecurID_getpasswd, ResMerger, 
Rez, RezDet, RezWack, Rscript, SetFile, SplitForks, UnRezWack, WSMakeStubs, 
a2p, a2p5.10.0, a2p5.8.9, aaf_install, aclocal, aclocal-1.10, addftinfo, 
afconvert, afinfo, afmtodit, afplay, afscexpand, agvtool, alias, allmemory, 
amavisd, amavisd-agent, amavisd-nanny, amavisd-release, amlint, ant, 
applesingle, appletviewer, apply, apr-1-config, apropos, apt, apu-1-config, 
ar, arch, as, asa, at, atos, atq, atrm, atsutil, autoconf, autoheader, 
autom4te, automake, automake-1.10, automator, autoreconf, autoscan, 
autoupdate, auval, auvaltool, awk, banner, basename, bashbug, batch, bbdiff, 
bbedit, bbfind, bc, bg, biff, binhex, bison, bitesize.d, bsdmake, bsdtar, 
bspatch, bundle, bunzip2, bzcat, bzcmp, bzdiff, bzegrep, bzfgrep, bzgrep, 
bzip2, bzip2recover, bzless, bzmore, c++, c++-4.0, c++-4.2, c++filt, c2ph, 
c2ph5.10.0, c2ph5.8.9, c89, c99, c_rehash, cal, calendar, cancel, cap, 
cap_mkdb, capify, captoinfo, cc, cd, certtool, checknr, chflags, chfn, chgrp, 
chpass, chsh, chudRemoteCtrl, chumAddRights, ci, cksum, clang, clang++, clear, 
cmp, cmpdylib, co, codesign, codesign_allocate, col, colcrt, colldef, colrm, 
column, comm, command, compileHelp, compile_et, compress, config, config_data, 
config_data5.10.0, config_data5.8.9, corelist, corelist5.10.0, corelist5.8.9, 
cpan, cpan2dist, cpan2dist5.10.0, cpan5.10.0, cpan5.8.9, cpanp, 
cpanp-run-perl, cpanp-run-perl5.10.0, cpanp5.10.0, cpio, cpp, cpp-4.0, 
cpp-4.2, cpuwalk.d, crc32, crc325.10.0, crc325.8.9, creatbyproc.d, crlrefresh, 
crontab, csplit, csreq, ctags, ctf_insert, cu, cups-calibrate, cups-config, 
cupstestdsc, cupstestppd, curl, curl-config, cut, cvs, cvsbug, dappprof, 
dapptrace, db_codegen, db_hotbackup, dbilogstrip, dbilogstrip5.10.0, 
dbilogstrip5.8.9, dbiprof, dbiprof5.10.0, dbiprof5.8.9, dbiproxy, 
dbiproxy5.10.0, dbiproxy5.8.9, dc, defaults, desdp, diff, diff3, diffpp, 
diffstat, dig, dirname, diskhits, dispqlen.d, distcc, distccd, distccmon-text, 
ditto, dns-sd, dprofpp, dprofpp5.10.0, dprofpp5.8.9, drutil, dscacheutil, 
dscl, dserr, dsexport, dsimport, dsmemberutil, dsperfmonitor, dsymutil, 
dtruss, du, dwarfdump, dyldinfo, easy_install, easy_install-2.5, 
easy_install-2.6, efax, efix, egrep, emacs, emacs-i386, emacs-undumped, 
emacsclient, enc2xs, enc2xs5.10.0, enc2xs5.8.9, encode_keychange, enscript, 
env, eqn, eqn2graph, erb, errinfo, erubis, escputil, etags, eventlogadm, ex, 
execsnoop, expand, expect, extcheck, false, fax, fc, fddist, ferret-browser, 
fetchmail, fetchmailconf, fg, fgrep, file, filebyproc.d, filtercalltree, find, 
find2perl, find2perl5.10.0, find2perl5.8.9, findsmb, findtr, findtr-4.7, 
finger, fixproc, flex, flex++, fmt, fold, formail, from, fs_usage, ftp, 
funzip, fuser, fwkdp, fwkpfv, g++, g++-4.0, g++-4.2, gatherheaderdoc, gcc, 
gcc-4.0, gcc-4.2, gcov, gcov-4.0, gcov-4.2, gdb, gdiffmk, gem, 
gen_bridge_metadata, gencat, genstrings, getconf, getopt, getopts, git, 
git-cvsserver, git-receive-pack, git-shell, git-upload-archive, 
git-upload-pack, gitk, glibtool, glibtoolize, gluedialect, gluedialect5.10.0, 
gluedialect5.8.9, gluedoc, gluedoc5.10.0, gluedoc5.8.9, glueedit, 
glueedit5.10.0, glueedit5.8.9, gluemac, gluemac5.10.0, gluemac5.8.9, 
gluescriptadds, gluescriptadds5.10.0, gluescriptadds5.8.9, gm4, gnuattach, 
gnuclient, gnudoit, gnumake, gnuplot, gnuserv, gnutar, gperf, gpgen, gprof, 
grap2graph, grep, grn, grodvi, groff, groffer, grog, grolbp, grolj4, grops, 
grotty, groups, gunzip, gzcat, gzexe, gzip, h2ph, h2ph5.10.0, h2ph5.8.9, h2xs, 
h2xs5.10.0, h2xs5.8.9, hash, hdid, hdiutil, hdxml2manxml, head, 
headerdoc2html, heap, hexdump, hiutil, host, hostinfo, hotspot.d, hpftodit, 
httpdstat.d, hwprefs, i686-apple-darwin10-cpp-4.2.1, 
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.0.1, i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1, 
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1, i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1, 
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2, i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2, ibtool, 
ibtoold, iconv, id, ident, idle, idle2.5, idle2.6, idlj, ifnames, indent, 
indxbib, info, infocmp, infokey, infotocap, install, install-info, 
install_name_tool, instmodsh, instmodsh5.10.0, instmodsh5.8.9, instruments, 
iodbc-config, iodbctest, iodbctestw, iofile.d, iofileb.d, iopattern, 
iopending, iosnoop, iotop, ipcount, ipcount5.10.0, ipcount5.8.9, ipcrm, ipcs, 
iprofiler, iptab, iptab5.10.0, iptab5.8.9, irb, isc-config.sh, jar, jarsigner, 
java, javac, javaconfig, javadoc, javah, javap, javatool, javaws, jconsole, 
jdb, jhat, jinfo, jmap, jobs, join, jot, jps, jrunscript, jsadebugd, jstack, 
jstat, jstatd, jvisualvm, kdestroy, kextutil, keytool, kill.d, killall, kinit, 
klist, kpasswd, krb5-config, kswitch, kvno, lam, last, lastcomm, lastwords, 
latency, lconvert, lconvert-4.7, ld, ld_classic, ldapadd, ldapcompare, 
ldapdelete, ldapexop, ldapmodify, ldapmodrdn, ldappasswd, ldapsearch, 
ldapwhoami, leaks, leave, less, lessc, lessecho, lesskey, lex, libnetcfg, 
libnetcfg5.10.0, libnetcfg5.8.9, libtool, lipo, lkbib, llvm-cpp-4.2, llvm-g++, 
llvm-g++-4.2, llvm-gcc, llvm-gcc-4.2, loads.d, locale, localedef, locate, 
lockfile, logger, login, logname, look, lookbib, lorder, lp, lpoptions, 
lppasswd, lpq, lpr, lprm, lpstat, lrelease, lrelease-4.7, lsbom, lsdistcc, 
lsm, lsvfs, lupdate, lupdate-4.7, lwp-download, lwp-download5.10.0, 
lwp-download5.8.9, lwp-mirror, lwp-mirror5.10.0, lwp-mirror5.8.9, lwp-request, 
lwp-request5.10.0, lwp-request5.8.9, lwp-rget, lwp-rget5.10.0, lwp-rget5.8.9, 
m4, mDNS, macbinary, macdeployqt, macdeployqt-4.7, macerror, macerror5.10.0, 
macerror5.8.9, machine, mail, mailq, mailstat, mailx, make, makeinfo, 
malloc_history, man, manpath, mcxquery, mcxrefresh, md, mdcheckschema, mdfind, 
mdimport, mdls, mdutil, mediastreamsegmenter, memcached, memcached-debug, 
memcached_top, merge, mesg, mib2c, mib2c-update, mig, mkafmmap, mkbom, mkdep, 
mkfifo, mklocale, mktemp, mmroff, mnthome, moc, moc-4.7, mongrel_rails, more, 
mp2bug, mpic++, mpicc, mpicxx, mpiexec, mpif77, mpif90, mpirun, msgs, mvn, 
nano, nasm, native2ascii, nbdst, nc, ncal, ncurses5.4-config, ndisasm, neqn, 
net, net-snmp-config, newaliases, newgrp, newproc.d, nfsstat, nice, nl, nm, 
nmblookup, nmedit, nohup, notificationconf, notifyutil, nroff, nslookup, 
nsupdate, ntlm_auth, ntp-keygen, ntpq, od, ompi_info, opal_wrapper, open, 
opendiff, opensnoop, openssl, orbd, orted, orterun, osacompile, osadecompile, 
osalang, osascript, otool, over, pack200, pagesize, pagestuff, passwd, paste, 
patch, pathchk, pathopens.d, pbcopy, pbpaste, pcap-config, pcast, pcastaction, 
pcastlibrary, pcsctest, pcsctool, pdbedit, pdfroff, pear, peardev, pecl, perl, 
perl5.10.0, perl5.8.9, perlbug, perlbug5.10.0, perlbug5.8.9, perlcc, 
perlcc5.8.9, perldoc, perldoc5.10.0, perldoc5.8.9, perlivp, perlivp5.10.0, 
perlivp5.8.9, perlthanks, perlthanks5.8.9, pfbtops, phar, phar.phar, php, 
php-config, phpize, pic, pic2graph, pico, piconv, piconv5.10.0, piconv5.8.9, 
pidpersec.d, pkgbuild, pl, pl2pm, pl2pm5.10.0, pl2pm5.8.9, plockstat, plutil, 
pmset, pod2html, pod2html5.10.0, pod2html5.8.9, pod2latex, pod2latex5.10.0, 
pod2latex5.8.9, pod2man, pod2man5.10.0, pod2man5.8.9, pod2readme, 
pod2readme5.10.0, pod2readme5.8.9, pod2text, pod2text5.10.0, pod2text5.8.9, 
pod2usage, pod2usage5.10.0, pod2usage5.8.9, podcast, podchecker, 
podchecker5.10.0, podchecker5.8.9, podselect, podselect5.10.0, podselect5.8.9, 
policytool, post-grohtml, powerpc-apple-darwin10-cpp-4.2.1, 
powerpc-apple-darwin10-g++-4.0.1, powerpc-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1, 
powerpc-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1, powerpc-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1, ppdc, 
ppdhtml, ppdi, ppdmerge, ppdpo, pr, pre-grohtml, priclass.d, pridist.d, 
printenv, printf, prl_disk_tool, prl_perf_ctl, prlctl, prlsrvctl, procmail, 
procsystime, productbuild, productsign, profiles, projectInfo, prove, 
prove5.10.0, prove5.8.9, psed, psed5.10.0, psed5.8.9, pstopdf, pstruct, 
pstruct5.10.0, pstruct5.8.9, ptar, ptar5.10.0, ptar5.8.9, ptardiff, 
ptardiff5.10.0, ptardiff5.8.9, pubsub, pump, purge, pwpolicy, pydoc, pydoc2.5, 
pydoc2.6, python, python-config, python2.5, python2.5-config, python2.6, 
python2.6-config, pythonw, pythonw2.5, pythonw2.6, qc2movie, 
qcollectiongenerator, qcollectiongenerator-4.7, qdbus, qdbus-4.7, 
qdbuscpp2xml, qdbuscpp2xml-4.7, qdbusxml2cpp, qdbusxml2cpp-4.7, qdoc3, 
qdoc3-4.7, qhelpgenerator, qhelpgenerator-4.7, qlmanage, qmake, qmake-4.7, 
qt3to4, qt3to4-4.7, qtdefaults, quartz-wm, quota, rackup, rails, rake, 
rake2thor, ranlib, rb-keygen, rcc, rcc-4.7, rcs, rcs2log, rcsclean, rcsdiff, 
rcsmerge, rdoc, read, readlink, rebase, redcloth, redo_prebinding, refer, 
renice, reset, rev, ri, rlog, rlogin, rmic, rmid, rmiregistry, rpcclient, 
rpcgen, rs, rsh, rsync, ruby, runocc.d, ruptime, rvictl, rview, rvim, 
rwbypid.d, rwbytype.d, rwho, rwsnoop, s2p, s2p5.10.0, s2p5.8.9, sample, 
sampleproc, sandbox-exec, sandbox-simplify, sar, say, sc_usage, schemagen, 
scp, screen, script, sdef, sdiff, sdp, security, sed, seeksize.d, segedit, 
serialver, servertool, setregion, setuids.d, sftp, shar, shark, shasum, 
shasum5.10.0, shlock, showmount, sigdist.d, sips, size, sliceprint, slogin, 
smbcacls, smbclient, smbcontrol, smbcquotas, smbget, smbpasswd, smbspool, 
smbstatus, smbtar, smbtree, smbutil, smtpd.py, smtpd2.5.py, smtpd2.6.py, 
snmpbulkget, snmpbulkwalk, snmpconf, snmpdelta, snmpdf, snmpget, snmpgetnext, 
snmpinform, snmpnetstat, snmpset, snmpstatus, snmptable, snmptest, 
snmptranslate, snmptrap, snmpusm, snmpvacm, snmpwalk, sntp, soelim, sort, 
spfd, spfd5.10.0, spfd5.8.9, spfquery, spfquery5.10.0, spfquery5.8.9, splain, 
splain5.10.0, splain5.8.9, split, sqlite3, srm, ssh, ssh-add, ssh-agent, 
ssh-keygen, ssh-keyscan, stat, states, stringdups, strings, strip, su, sudo, 
sum, svn, svnadmin, svndumpfilter, svnlook, svnserve, svnsync, svnversion, 
sw_vers, swig, syscallbypid.d, syscallbyproc.d, syscallbysysc.d, syslog, 
tab2space, tabs, tail, talk, tar, tbl, tclsh, tclsh8.4, tclsh8.5, tconf, 
tdbbackup, tdbdump, tdbtool, tee, telnet, testparm, testrb, texi2dvi, 
texi2html, texi2pdf, texindex, textutil, tfmtodit, tftp, thor, tic, tidy, 
tiff2icns, tiffutil, time, tkcon, tkmib, tnameserv, toe, top, tops, 
topsyscall, topsysproc, touch, tput, tr, traptoemail, trial, troff, true, 
tset, tsort, tt, tty, twistd, type, uic, uic-4.7, uic3, uic3-4.7, ul, ulimit, 
umask, unalias, uname, uncompress, unexpand, unifdef, unifdefall, uniq, units, 
unpack200, unvis, unwinddump, unzip, unzipsfx, update_dyld_shared_cache, 
uptime, users, uucp, uudecode, uuencode, uuidgen, uulog, uuname, uupick, 
uustat, uuto, uux, vers_string, vgrind, vi, view, vim, vimdiff, vimtutor, vis, 
vm_stat, vmmap, w, wait, wall, wbinfo, wc, weblatency.d, what, whatis, 
whereis, which, who, whoami, whois, wish, wish8.4, wish8.5, write, wsgen, 
wsimport, wx-config, wxPerl, wxPerl5.10.0, wxPerl5.8.9, wxperl_demo.pl, 
wxperl_demo5.10.0.pl, wxperl_demo5.8.9.pl, wxperl_overload, 
wxperl_overload5.10.0, wxperl_overload5.8.9, wxperl_xspp, wxperl_xspp5.10.0, 
wxperl_xspp5.8.9, wxrc, wxrc-2.8, xar, xargs, xattr, xattr-2.5, xattr-2.6, 
xcman, xcode-select, xcodebuild, xcodeindex, xcrun, xgettext.pl, 
xgettext5.10.0.pl, xgettext5.8.9.pl, xgrid, xjc, xml2-config, xml2man, 
xmlcatalog, xmllint, xmlpatterns, xmlpatterns-4.7, xmlwf, xpath, xpath5.10.0, 
xpath5.8.9, xslt-config, xsltproc, xsubpp, xsubpp5.10.0, xsubpp5.8.9, xxd, 
yacc, yes, ypcat, ypmatch, ypwhich, zcat, zcmp, zdiff, zegrep, zfgrep, zforce, 
zgrep, zip, zipcloak, zipgrep, zipinfo, zipnote, zipsplit, zless, zmore, znew, 
zprint`
```

Comment: This gives a list of CURRENTLY installed programs. What about FACTORY installed, for each release of OSX? This must be listed somewhere...

Comment: Think that list may need a little trimming. For example, `bbdiff, bbedit, bbfind`, are from BBEdit, which is a third party app. Likewise, many others are only available after installing the Xcode developer tools, which aren't installed by default. (Not sure if the OP meant to include those or not).

Comment: I'm a little surprised the BBEdit tools are in /usr/bin. I would have assumed they would be installed in /usr/local/bin. I didn't think about what would have been installed by Xcode. For what it's worth, I've never intentionally installed anything in /usr/bin, only /usr/local/bin and /opt/local/bin. So this should be a decent representation of what's installed on a Snow Leopard system with Xcode.

Comment: I am looking for what a Mac has installed when you *walk out of the Apple store.*

Comment: I don't have `findsmb` installed.  10.12.4.